# Is it possible to create dynamic theme in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

I can create static theme as described in [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes.html) which I guess can not be modified at runtime. I need some way or API for changing theme properties at runtime. Is it possible to do it with Chrome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible right now.
Sorry