# Programmatically change Chrome tab color using Chrome Extensions API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to figure out how to change the tab color of a Chrome tab programmatically. I am creating a Chrome Extension that records user actions on a page; while recording is happening, I want the browser tab color to change. Once recording is done, the tab would change back to the original color.

Does anyone know how to programmatically change the color of a tab? I am not sure if this is synonymous with changing the Chrome theme/skin, but it might be.

Here is some documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes

but it's not clear how to change the theme dynamically. Note, I would like to just change one tab's color, not all the tabs. This might not be possible.

Comment: This is the closest thing I have found, but it might be particular to Android: https://gordonlesti.com/change-theme-color-via-javascript/

Comment: This is also of note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420652/is-it-possible-to-create-dynamic-theme-in-chrome

Comment: Chrome doesn't have an API to change the theme dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`. The extensions->theme key might be what you're looking for.